# How I can calculate $g^{(1)}$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be an analytic function defined over all complex plane. Now, consider the function $g:ℝ^{r+1}→ℝ$ defined by

$$g(t₁,t₂,...,t_{r+1})=f^{(r+1)}(1-2∏_{j=1}^{r+1}t_{j})$$

where $f^{(r+1)}$ is the $r+1$-th derivatives of $f$. We make a restriction of $f$ to the reals.

My **question** is:

How I can calculate $g^{(1)}$? the first derivative of $g$ with respect to $t_{j}$.

Comment: The first derivative of $g$ with respect to $t_{j}$.

Comment: That's rather denoted by $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t_j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t_i}\prod_{j=1}^{r+1}t_{j}=\prod_{j\neq i}t_{j}.
$$
So by the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t_i}=f^{(r+2)}\left(1-2 \prod_{j=1}^{r+1}t_{j}\right)\cdot\left(-2\prod_{j\neq i}t_{j}\right)=-2\left(\prod_{j\neq i}t_{j}\right)f^{(r+2)}\left(1-2 \prod_{j=1}^{r+1}t_{j}\right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Chain rule:

$$ \frac\partial {\partial t_k}g = -2\prod_{j\ne k}t_j\cdot f^{(r+2)}(1-2\prod_j t_j)$$